# main.cc:5:30: fatal error: folder/file.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

When I use type `make` into Ubuntu terminal I get:

```
main.cc:5:30: fatal error: folder/file.h: No such file or directory
```

The folder exists in the working directory and the file.h exists in the specified folder.

When I type `ls` it lists the folder and file in my working directory as well.

Oddly enough, when I open it in geany and ask it to find the file in the

```
#include <folder/file.h>
```

it finds it without issue but when it builds it I get the error.

Is there a flag I need to set so it so it includes the folder?  If so, what would that look like exactly?

Comment: If "folder" is in the same directory as your source file, use `#include "folder/file.h"`

Comment: @Malloc, also need add `-I` during compile

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This depends a bit on your C compiler, but "typically" when you include a file using the `< ... >` syntax the compiler will only look for those header files in directories you have specified on the command line with the `-I` flag, plus various built-in system directories.

Notably, it usually will *not* look in the current working directory, unless you explicitly add `-I.` to the compile line.

Alternatively, if you use the `" ... "` form of `#include`, then it will look in the current working directory as well.

So, either switch to `#include "folder/file.h"`, or else add `-I.` to your compile line.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  Althoguht he others ones worked as well, this is what I needed to do to for this build.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use quotes instead of `<>` for the include, this makes it that the compiler searches in the source file's directory first:

```
#include "folder/file.h"
```

Alternatively explicitly add the current directory to your include paths

```
g++ c -I. main.cc
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding you question, I think first you need tell the compiler, where is you head file, since you write your code as:

```
#include <folder/file.h>
```

I assumed that you store your file.h in `$you/include/path/folder`, therefore, you need pass `-I ${your/include/path/}` to compiler like:

```
gcc -I${your/include/path/} ...
```

be aware, you specified in your code the include as `<dir/file.h>`, I think this kinds of define show following idea:

```
$main_include_path
|
+----folder1
|
+----folder2
|
.
.
.----folderN
```

Then, you can ONLY write `makefile` to specified the include path to it father